# Ignore spaces, including ~

Tags: luatex, french

The title says it all, how can I ignore spaces, like `\ignorespaces` does, but including a `~` ?

The reason I ask is we are multiple authors writing a document, and they have different habits with respect to typing French guillemets in their source code (ie. `«bla»`, `« bla »` and `«~bla~»`), and I want to unify this by setting a `\newunicodechar{«}` with the appropriate definition.

For the closing guillemet, `\unskip` seems to do the trick in all cases.

Comment: ```\catcode`~=10``` would change the category code of the tilda `~` into a space which could then be ignored by `\ignorespaces`. I am not sure if this would work but worth a try.

Comment: Open a group, define ~ as `\relax`, close it on closing guillemet?

Comment: You have set the `luatex` tag -- does this mean that using LuaLaTeX is an option for you and your coauthors? Please confirm.

Comment: If you are using babel-french together with luatex, I can provide an easy fix to frenchb.lua which will output the right thing in your three cases «a», « b » and «~c~».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It defines a Lua function that does most of the work, plus a couple of LaTeX utility macros that activate and deactivate the Lua function. By "activate", I mean "assign the Lua function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback", so that it may act as a preprocessor on the input stream *before* TeX starts its usual processing.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % for "\og" and "\fg" macros
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes} % for "\enquote" macro

\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment
%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function delete_whitespace ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( "«[ ~]*" , "\\og " )
  s = s:gsub ( "[ ~]*»" , "\\fg " )
  -- s = s:gsub ( "[ ~]+([%:%;%?%!])" , "%1" ) -- if needed
  return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% LaTeX-side code
\newcommand\DeletewhitespaceOn{\luadirect{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
    "process_input_buffer", delete_whitespace , "deletewhitespace" )}}
\newcommand\DeletewhitespaceOff{\luadirect{luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
    "process_input_buffer", "deletewhitespace" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\DeletewhitespaceOn} % enable by default

\begin{document}
\enquote{bla} \og{}bla\fg{}  «bla»  « bla »  «~bla~»  «~ bla ~ » 

\DeletewhitespaceOff
\enquote{bla} \og{}bla\fg{}  «bla»  « bla »  «~bla~»  «~ bla ~ » 
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you want to automatically get nobreak spaces after `«` and before `»` with babel-french, you have to add `\frenchbsetup{og=«, fg=»}`.   Otherwise, you could change the gsub outputs to `\og{}` and `\fg{}`.

Comment: @DanielFlipo - I'm not sure I follow you. For sure, the Lua code I posted above does *not* operate on `\og` and `\fg`. Please clarify.

Comment: I was thinking about changing  `s = s:gsub ( "«[ ~]+" , "«" )` into  `s = s:gsub ( "«[ ~]+" , "\og " )`  for instance (not tested).  On the other hand `\frenchbsetup{og=«, fg=»}` will add the proper (nobreak) spaces required in French with your original code.

Comment: @DanielFlipo - (I think `"\\og "`, not `"\og "`, is needed in the argument of `gsub`.) As long as we can be sure that the outputs of `«` and `\og` are the same -- which I believe is indeed supposed to be the case in French typography, but do please correct me if I'm wrong -- I guess it's ok to encode the opening-guillemet character as `«`.

Comment: Of course `\\og `, not `\og `, my mistake.  Actually `\og ` outputs a `«` *followed by a nobreak space*.   A bare  `«`  character in the source will be output as  `«` … unless a `\frenchbsetup{og=«, fg=»}` command is found in the preamble.

Comment: @DanielFlipo -- Sorry for being so slow on the uptake regarding  your comments. I finally figured out where I had gone wrong and managed to misunderstand your suggestions. I've now updated the code to make the Lua function output `\og` and `\fg` instead of `«` and `»`, respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much ! LuaLaTeX really offers new possibilities ! I settled for a luacode* environment to avoid escaping ``\og`` and ``\fg``. I also added a ``s = s:gsub ( [["(.-)"]], [[\og %1\fg{}]])`` to catch usage of English quotes…

Comment: @DanielFlipo ``\frenchbsetup{og=«, fg=»}`` by itself does bring automatic spacing, but the actual guillemets are displayed as ż and another letter…

Comment: @ysalmon I must be missing something. If you are using lualatex or xelatex, it should work out of the box. If you are using pdflatex, please consider coding your input file in utf8! otherwise you have to specify the input encoding by `\usepackage[...]{inputenc}, babel-french will then output French quotes correctly.

Comment: @DanielFlipo Apparently, that is because we say ``\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`` in the preamble. Not sure if we should.

Comment: If you are compiling with luatex (or xetex) you *surely shouldn't*. Both engines use TU encoding, do *not* load explicitly the `fontenc` package.

Comment: @ysalmon - By all means, do *not* load the `fontenc` or `inputenc` packages in documents that are to be compiled with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Aside: Did you notice that the test document shown above does not load the `fontenc` or `inputenc` packages? That was not by accident.

Answer (score 2):

With expl3 it's really easy (although because of the extreme generality of the relevant functions, the performance might not be ideal):

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newunicodechar{×}{123\ignorespaces}
\newunicodechar{≡}{123\peek_regex_remove_once:nT{(\cA\~|\cS\ )+}{}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}



× 456

×~456 %unfortunately does not work

% all of the below works:
≡ 456

≡~456

≡~~456

≡~ ~ 456

\end{document}
```

Just to demonstrate here I use 2 irrelevant Unicode characters.

Performance could be optimized a bit by precompiling the regex:

```
\regex_new:N \l_ysalmon_regex
\regex_set:Nn \l_ysalmon_regex {(\cA\~|\cS\ )+}
\newunicodechar{≡}{123\peek_regex_remove_once:NT\l_ysalmon_regex{}}
```

(variable named according to the OP's username. Change if needed)

The `peek` family of functions does not handle some corner cases correctly, but it's so rare it's virtually impossible to come up in practice.

Comment: Remove the `+` if you only need to remove at most 1 space characters.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to remove all glue, kerns and penalties before a closing guillemet than to remove what's after an opening one.

Anyway, this should be fairly efficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{«}{<<\ignoreallspaces}
\newunicodechar{»}{\removeallspaces~>>}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeallspaces}{}
 {
  \int_case:nnT { \lastnodetype }
   {
    {11}{\unskip}
    {12}{\unkern}
    {13}{\unpenalty}
   }
   {\removeallspaces}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ignoreallspaces}{}
 {
  \peek_remove_filler:n { \peek_charcode_remove:NT \c_tilde_str { \ignoreallspaces } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

« ~ a ~~ »

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would like to mention that babel-french v3.5o fixes the issue (for the LuaTeX engine only): coding `«bla»` or `« bla »` or `«~bla~»` produces the same output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchsetup{og=«, fg=»}
\begin{document}
«bla»  « bla »  «~bla~» \frquote{bla}
\end{document}
```

prints

[image]